# Email notification when a new subscriber enters a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is there a way to send out an automated email notification (to a pre-defined email address) every time a new subscriber enters a Data Extension in SFMC?

Thanks

Comment: How are you loading subscribers into the DE ?

Comment: Web Collect form. Every time a form on the website is submitted, a DE in SFMC gets populated with the submitted data.

Comment: You could have a automation run a query to check for this and include a validation step. Did you want to be notified on a per entry basis or would a summary of all entries in the last hour (if any are added) be sufficient?

Comment: Per entry basis would be ideal otherwise hourly summary would do. Does the automation need to have further actions (eg. send email) by design or can it stop at the validation step?

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1: Use AMPscripting to calculate new records**

Step 1: Create a simple email that will have following ampscripting  (my example uses new records today but you can tweak this to new records in the past hour).

```
%%[
VAR @currentSystemTime, @Today
SET @currentSystemTime = NOW()
SET @Today= FormatDate(SystemDateToLocalDate(@currentSystemTime), "YYYY-MM-DD")
]%%
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @i
set @rows = LookupRows("TestDE","SubmissionDate",@Today)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @rowCount do
var @EmailAddress
set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
set @EmailAddress = field(@row,"EmailAddress")
]%%
```

Step 2: Set up an automation that runs on your cadence, with the email in Step 1.

*Pros*: Not too many steps
*Cons*: An email will be send based on the cadence you chose, even if 0 records were added.

**Approach 2: Use SQL to calculate new records**

Step 1: Create a field named Entry_Dt (data type: date; nullable field; set default value to current date).  Whenever a record is inserted into the DE, the current date will be added to the record.

Step 2: Build a new DE that will capture results of SQL that will run in Step 3.

Step 3: Build a SQL query that returns all records that were inserted into the DE in the past hour (or your preferred cadence), based on the Entry_Dt field in Step 1.

Step 4: Create a list of email addresses who should receive this new records emails by building a list under Subscribers > My Subscribers > My Lists.

Step 5: Build a simple email that captures the results from the DE that you created in Step 2.

Step 6: Build an automation that runs the SQL, add a validation rule that check how many new records exist.  If > 0, then Send email, else end automation.

*Pros*: Only sends an email when new records are added.
*Cons*: More steps involved

Hope this helps!